# Access subplot elements of holoviews Gridspace

Tags: holoviews, hvplot

Is there a way to access individual subplots in a hv.Gridspace to overlay individual texts?
I'm using hvplot and like the convenient API to split plots by rows/columns as in 
`gs = df.hvplot(x='x', y='y', datashade=True, row='row', col='col')`, using the bokeh backend.

However I'd like to overlay some text (with statistics on the data) specific to each subplot. When setting text with `gs * hv.Text(0,0, 'some text')`, the text will show up in each subplot in the GridSpace.
While using a Layout would probably give that flexibility, I like the way Gridspace is arranged with no inner axes and the row/column categories being annotated.